# A probabilistic proof of Oppenheim's inequality?

Tags: inequality, determinant, positive-semidefinite, jensen-inequality, hadamard-product

Oppenheim's inequality is a standard result about the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of positive definite matrices. It goes as follows, let $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\leq n},B=(b_{ij})_{i,j\leq n} \in S_n^{++}$ where $S_n^{++}$ denotes the cone of positive definite matrices of size $n$, and let $\odot$ denote the Hadamard product. Then
$$\det (A \odot B) \geq a_{11}...a_{nn} \det (B), $$
with equality if and only if $B$ is diagonal.

Most proofs (e.g. [Markham's](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2322329) in 1986) use induction. I thought I found a neat probabilistic proof based on Jensen's inequality. But it does not quite work, since we only prove the inequality up to a constant factor. Does anyone see a way to fix the proof?

**A proof that almost works**

The idea is to use the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371368/variance-of-hadamard-product) that, if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,A)$, and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,B)$ are independent, then $$ A \odot B = \text{Cov}(X \odot Y) = \mathbb{E} [  (X\odot Y) (X\odot Y)^T]. $$
An useful way to see Hadamard products between vectors is to note that $X\odot Y = D_X Y$, where $D_X$ is the diagonal matrix with $X$ on the diagonal. Using this,
$$ \mathbb{E} [  (X\odot Y)(X\odot Y)^T] = \mathbb{E} [ D_X Y Y^T D_X] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[D_X Y Y^T D_X | X ]] = \mathbb{E}[D_XBD_X], $$
using the law of total expectation.

Now, we can just use Jensen's inequality together with the concavity of the log-determinant:
\begin{align}
\log (\det A \odot B) =  \log \det \mathbb{E}[D_XBD_X] \geq \mathbb{E}[ \log \det (D_XBD_X )] &= \log \det B + \mathbb{E}[ \log \det(D_X^2)] \\ &= \log \det B + \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\log x_i^2].
\end{align}
Here we would really like to use that $\mathbb{E}[x_i^2] = a_{ii}$ and conclude the proof, but Jensen's inequality is the other way around this time :(

We still have proven something, since, because $X$ is Gaussian, for each $i$, $x_i^2/a_{ii}$ will follow a $\chi^2$ distribution with a single degree of freedom, and therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[\log x_i^2] = \mathbb{E}[\log x_i^2/a_{ii}] + \log a_{ii} = \psi(1/2)+\log(2) + \log a_{ii} = -\log(2) - \gamma + \log a_{ii}, $$
using the [properties of the $\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) ($\psi$ is the digamma function, and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant).

Putting all the pieces together, we have then proven that
$$\log (\det A \odot B) \geq \log \det B + \sum_{i=1}^n \log a_{ii} - n(\gamma + \log 2) \approx \log \det B + \sum_{i=1}^n \log a_{ii} - 1.27n. $$

Oppenheim's inequality is exactly this, but, without this annoying $1.27n$ additional term! My question is then: is there a way to make a version of this proof with a tight bound?

**Reference**

Markham, Oppenheim's Inequality for Positive Definite Matrices, *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 93, No. 8, pp. 642-644, 1986